# deleteByQuery working via XML call but not JSON for multi condition query

Tags: json, xml, solr

Is Solr's delete query syntax different when passing JSON data vs XML data? Solr's [docs](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/UpdateJSON#Update_Commands) are rather vague.  I'm using Solr 5.0.0 on Mac OSX on Java 1.8.

Here are the curl commands on my local box.

```
curl -v http://localhost:8983/solr/nZ/update -H "Content-Type: application/json" --data-binary

[
{
    "delete": {
        "query":"UserId:5629499534213120 AND SessionId:5066549580791808 AND Kind:event"
    }
}
]
```

This outputs:

```
{
    "responseHeader": {
        "status": 400,
        "QTime": 2
    },
    "error": {
        "msg": "Document is missing mandatory uniqueKey field: Id",
        "code": 400
    }
}
```

Running it via XML works:

```
curl -v http://localhost:8983/solr/nZ/update -H "Content-Type: text/xml" --data-binary '
<delete>
<query>UserId:5629499534213120 AND SessionId:5066549580791808 AND Kind:event</query>
</delete>
'
```

This deletes the documents and outputs:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<response>
<lst name="responseHeader"><int name="status">0</int><int name="QTime">57</int></lst>
</response>
```

I also queried the documents I'm trying to delete. There were only 2 of them and they both had the Id fields. Id is a string and the unique key for the schema. Is the query syntax for a multi condition different for JSON than XML?

Answer (score 1):

JSON update format in Solr is a bit picky. And it seems you mixed two very-similar looking structures. The array outer [] structure is for when you are just submitting documents with no commands.

The object {} outer structure is when you have commands and documents.

You have mixed those two. Try deleting outer array structure and see if it helps. Notice that Solr does allow/require duplicate keys within the object for this second format, which some libraries can't handle generating. In which case, you may be limited to only one instance of the same update command per document.